# How to disable Num Lock/Caps Lock notification - missing settings

Tags: windows-10, display-settings, capslock, numlock

I have a script that keeps my computer awake by switching the num lock on and off every few seconds (this is needed, there is no alternative to this). Ever since last week, a num lock notification is showing up on the top of my screen every few seconds. I have followed multiple 'solutions' to disable this, but I can't see the settings they refer to.

Multiple articles have said to go to **Settings** > **System** > **Display** > **Advanced display settings** > **Display adapter properties for Display 1** and then a window pops up where there is a **Screen configurations** tab where you can uncheck **Enable on-screen display**.

I can't find this tab anywhere and would like to know where else I can find this setting to disable the num lock and caps lock notification.

Below are the options I can see inside **Advanced display settings**.

[Screenshot of setting options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dmlf.png)
[Screenshot of notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KniKq.png)

Comment: The notification is not built-into Windows which means third-party software is doing it.  What third-party software by the OEM do you have installed?

Comment: Why would you think their is no alternative. Windows has a way of doing this designed in and it does not require programs to pretend to press keys. A thread in a program call `SetThreadExecutionState`. Here is a utility that calls it for you. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/keepdisplayon-runs-program-preventing.html. More info https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate. This is how media players etc prevent sleeping when running.

Comment: I have a Logitech G Hub running, maybe that is the culprit? I can't seem to find any setting in there about notifications though. In regards to the script, it's complicated but at the end of the day I just want to know how to disable the notification rather than a different way to keep the computer awake.

Comment: Its not a different way it is the correct way. There is a difference. You are asking why my non approved way doesn't work as I want. Because it is a non approved way.